# On iOS 6, PhoneGap 2.1 iPad app no longer autorotates

Tags: cordova, rotation, ios6, autorotate

When running the app on iOS 6, my app no longer successfully autorotates. I have updated to Cordova 2.1, and I have the following code in my `MainViewController.m` file (which is a subclass of `CDViewController`, to be compatible with the new iOS6 way of handling autorotation:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

// iOS 6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger ret = 0;

    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
        ret = ret | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown])
        ret = ret | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight])
        ret = ret | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
        ret = ret | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.m you need to add the following to **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

Once you add this, rotation should start working again. It has for my two apps.

Comment: I put the line of code and it works on an **iPad 2G** with **iOS 6.1** and **Cordova 1.9.0**. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Still too new here to get the ability to vote up mattdryden's answer in this thread. However, I wanted to second his answer and, to add value, note that **his suggested fix also works for PhoneGap/Cordova 1.9**

I have a few apps that haven't been through the PhoneGap/Cordova 1.9 --> 2.0/2.1 update process yet and manually making the change suggested above in AppDelegate.m worked for those apps.

Also, it's worth adding that where you put that line seems to matter.

I initially added this line just before: return YES and it failed. It turns out that you need to place it **before** this line:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

One more thing.... to help Google/etc. find this problem faster... a key hint in the console log that you need to add this line is the following:

**Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**

Adding the line of code mentioned above makes this error go away...

Hope this helps others seeing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with my iPad app on iOS 6. This problem occurs because the MainViewController is not set to be the rootViewController in `AppDelegate.m`. In your `AppDelegate.m` replace:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

with

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```